# Getting "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: C" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull data from a number of sheets to one dashboard sheet. When I add more than sheet I get this error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: C

It works fine with only one sheet (July2022) but as soon as I add one or more to it I get the error.

```
=QUERY({JULY2022!A4:EC34;AUGUST2022!A4:EC34;SEPTEMBER2022!A4:EC34;OCTOBER2022!A4:EC34;NOVEMBER!A4:EC34;DECEMBER!A4:EC34},
"select C, A
where A >= date'"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
and C is not null
ORDER BY A ASC LIMIT 8"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap the data into curly braces, which is necessary when you combine multiple sources, you've to refer to the columns as Col1, Col2, Col3,... You can't use the column letters.

You can use:

```
=QUERY({JULY2022!A4:EC34;AUGUST2022!A4:EC34;SEPTEMBER2022!A4:EC34;OCTOBER2022!A4:EC34;NOVEMBER!A4:EC34;DECEMBER!A4:EC34},
"select Col3, Col1
where Col1 >= date'"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
and Col3 is not null
ORDER BY Col1 ASC LIMIT 8"
)
```